# Careers 2.0 cannot retrieve URL of article I wrote

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

On Careers 2.0, I tried to add "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_(type_theory)" as an article I wrote. (I tried both with and without the correct URL encoding of the parentheses.) It said it couldn't fetch the article for some reason.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem, perhaps wikipedia was having issues for a moment?  Can you please try it again?

Comment: Yes, it works now - thanks. Maybe it was an issue with an error response being cached somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have problem with special characters:

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda is working
http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-calcul is not.